# Flexdashboard: Storyboard does not work with ODBC and temporal environment variables

Tags: r, storyboard, odbc, dbi, flexdashboard

I am using `flexdashboard (0.5.2)`, `ODBC (1.3.3)` in **R 4.1.0** and **IDE RStudio (2021.09.2)** on a Server (not in my local machine)
I have being building flexdashboard storyboards and I wanted to "level up" my stories, connecting the data of the stories to the source (postgres database).
to do this, I normally:

1 - stablish system enviroment variables for password, user, and other parameters.
2 - Create a function that is loaded when the page is loaded, that open connection, extract table, close connection, and return data
Problem: when I Knit, it raise the error
(Tab Render)

```
Line XX Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][RStudio][PostgreSQL] (10) Error occurred while trying to connect: [SQLState 28000] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
 
Execution halted
```

(Tab Issue)

```
Quitting from lines 63-66 (main_flexdashboard.Rmd) 
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][RStudio][PostgreSQL] (10) Error occurred while trying to connect: [SQLState 28000] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
 
Execution halted
```

**Code to reproduce this error:**

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

get_db_table <- function(){ 
  #======================================================
  # 0. connection:
  print("connecting...")
  print(connList)
  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                        Driver = "PostgreSQL",
                        Database = "mydb",
                        #encoding = "windows-1252",
                        #encoding = "UTF-16",
                        UID = Sys.getenv("myuser"),
                        PWD = Sys.getenv("mypasswordwithspecialcharacters"),
                        host = myhost,
                        Port = 8888,
                        MultipleActiveResultSets = "True"
                        )

  #..........
  # In a normal case, here some code to get the table of interest ....
  #...............
  print("connected!")
  dbDisconnect(con)
  return("done----")
 #======================================================
}

 # here calling the function
 myT <- get_db_table ()
```

On the other hand:
I ) If I write the string with the password (something NOT recommendable) in the PWD field, it will work fine and smooth.
II) Also If I run the chuncks of code manually, instead of Knit the Rmd, it works fine too (it connects and return the table)

I already reported this in the [flexdashboard repository issues](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/404) but maybe anybody on this community knows about how to work around this issue.
Please let me know (I already tried several approaches, unsuccessfully)

Comment: Having the environment variable available in your IDE and having it available in an app's environment are two different things. Depending on the "serving" environment (shinyapps.io, shiny-server, Connect), you should have the ability to set envvars for the app itself. FYI, this separation is both necessary (computers don't share envvars) and useful, where you can have one set of connection parameters in dev mode and a different set in production.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY , I just realized my error was when setting up the temporal environments via `Sys.setenv(mypassw="thispassw")` . I did it WRONG: `Sys.setenv("mypassw"="thispassw")` because I quoted the name of the environment too. The first one is the good one and now it works. Thank you anyway for the clarification!

Comment: Quoting the envvar name changes nothing (unless the name is not a syntactically legal R object name), just like `mean("x"=5)` and `mean(x=5)` are functionally identical; not sure what else would have happened. Glad it is working again!